# App to manage your cloud files?

Tags: android, file-synchronization, cloud-service, google-apps

Is there any application (for Android or Windows) where I can do the management of cloud files?

For example synchronize the same file to my OneDrive accounts, Google Drive and other cloud services.

Comment: What operating system does it need to run on? Do you have a specific budget?

Comment: android operating system, if it exists for windows will also be welcome

Comment: What granularity do you want? Per directory/per file? Do you want *all* files copied to *all* cloud providers, or do you want to have different 'flows' from source to target destinations (in that case, give examples)? Does it have to be both ways or is only upload enough? It is also relevant to explicitly state which cloud services you want supported, because these kinds of programs differ in the services they support. Please [edit] *all* relevant information into your question.

Comment: As for Android, you might wish to take a look at my list of [MultiCloud-Manager](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman#group_1020)s. I'm not working with Windows, so I cannot help you with that. Also interesting: [Cloud Synchronisation apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync#group_162). Make your pick – if there's a "great match", be welcome to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :)

Comment: PS: For your example, it's the second list – and most likely called *FolderSync*. I've never tried cross-syncing (I only use my ownCloud), so I cannot make it an "answer by heart" – but using this app (paid version) for years and being happy with it, I can give a "general recommendation" at least ;)

Comment: As a workaround, use IFTTT.  When a new file appears in one cloud, copy it to the other(s).

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of AJC Sync for Windows.  The Pro edition which costs $35 will allow you to sync to multiple cloud accounts.  See [AJC Sync](https://www.ajcsoft.com/file-sync.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want a google drive app, one drive app, Dropbox app etc. keep running on all your laptops to sing all this. I have a system of keeping some of these services synced in one place. But it's a costly solution. It's a synology nas. The synology cloud sync software keeps Dropbox, box and google drive in one place in sync. On the nas. Then I use one app only (synology cloud) to get the folders I want to my pc's/laptop. I can decide to sync everything, making me able to manage all these cloud services in one place.